# Image error in hmvc CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

Image Location :

> application / modules / user / views / img / food.jpg

and my script :

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/modules/user/views/img/food.jpg">
```

Can you tell me the best way to show the image profile ?

Comment: I guess /application/modules/user/views/img/food.jpg might be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the folder says, `application` should be only used for the application, not for the public data like one image published on the html.

You should place the image outside the application folder. Like the `images` folder on the root of your project.

> - Root of your project
>   |- Application
>   |- cache
>   |- codeigniter
>   |- css
>   ...
>   |- **images <---------------- this one**
>   ....

And the link should be something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/food.jpg">
```